# package-lock.json -- how to fix version error

Tags: npm, github-actions

I'm setting up a GitHub action to automatically lint and test every commit. Unfortunately, the action always fails when npm is installing the dependencies.

In short, I think something's messed up with the package-lock.json and I need to regenerate it, somehow. Any ideas?

#### The error

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents/-/fsevents-2.2.3.tgz
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'fsevents@2.2.1' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-01-08T07_29_59_535Z-debug.log
```

I believe that's a result of this section of the package-lock.json

```
"fsevents": {
    "version": "2.2.1",
    "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents/-/fsevents-2.2.3.tgz",
    "integrity": "sha512-bTLYHSeC0UH/EFXS9KqWnXuOl/wHK5Z/d+ghd5AsFMYN7wIGkUCOJyzy88+wJKkZPGON8u4Z9f6U4FdgURE9qA==",
    "dev": true,
    "optional": true
}
```

Notice how the URL is different than the version number. [Fsevents never had a v2.2.3, only v2.2.2.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents)

Fsevents is not a direct dependency of this project (i.e., it's not in the package.json).

#### Debug steps

I've tried:

- `npm update`
- `npm audit fix`
- deleting the package-lock.json, then `npm install`
- `npm install --package-lock`
- manually editing the package-lock.json, but it just reverts back after an `npm install`
- on my computer (macOS Big Sur, Intel), I did `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`, but I have any issues installing or running the tests
- on my computer, I tried `npm ci` just like the action, no error or issues

#### The GitHub action

In case it makes a difference, here's the GitHub action:

```
name: Continuous integration

on: [push]

jobs:
  test-push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 14
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run lint
      - run: npm run test
```

The error occurs on the `npm ci` step.

[Update]: I also tried the Github Action on macOS with `runs-on: macos-latest`. Same error.

Comment: Do you have the same problem when you try to reproduce it on your computer?

Comment: Good question. I don't think so. I deleted the node_modules then npm install. No errors. macOS Big Sur. I assume that's how you'd test it.

Updated the initial post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to both delete the node_modules and package-lock.json. Doing only one of the two didn't work.

```
rm -rm node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm i
```